# why comparisons operators are so quick?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

According to the Alexandrescu article https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920/

> The speed hierarchy of operations is:
>
> 1. comparisons
> 2. (u)int add, subtract, bitops, shift
> 3. floating point add, sub (separate unit!)
> 4. indexed array access (caveat: cache effects)
> 5. (u)int32 mul
> 6. FP mul
> 7. FP division, remainder
> 8. (u)int division,remainder

I don't understand why comparisons are so quick.

How it's possible to quickly compare two large number? What is the algorithm?

Comment: IMHO, (integer) comparsion is as fast as (integer) subtraction because effectively it _is_ subtration with discarded result — except processor state flags Z, N, V, C.

Comment: `IMHO, (integer) comparsion is as fast as (integer) subtraction because effectively it is subtration` You're talking about the `cmp` instruction, there is another one, `test`, which does a bitwise AND.

Comment: @ReAl I would've guessed the same. On the other hand, it's Alexandrescu. (I've one of his books in my shelf.) ;-) Could it be that _discarded result_ makes compare even faster. (It doesn't need to write back the result.) A look into a machine command cycle table would help...

Comment: [Agner Fog's website](https://www.agner.org/optimize/) is a good source for such occasions. He has [Instruction tables for Intel, AMD, and VIA CPUs](https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

Comment: `cmp` is not really faster than `add` by itself, but an arith-branch pair (including `add+jz` though!, not just combinations with `cmp`) costs about the same as the branch alone would, in that sense a `cmp` can sometimes be added "for free"

Comment: @tkausl In my opinion, `test` (`and` with discarded result) is not purely "comparsion" but it does not matter, all `add`, `sub`, `cmp`, `and`, `or`, `xor` (more "comparsion" than `and`), `test`, also `inc`, `dec` and bitwise shifts, are done in the same operational block, simplest integer ALU. All have the same shortest time — one ALU operation with the same throughput.

Comment: The relative speed of operations will vary somewhat depending on the overall architecture and details of the CPU.  Is there specific hardware you're asking about, or that was mentioned in the linked article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These comparisons are quick because they are easy. The article in question is talking about comparisons of numeric values. In general, these fall into two types: comparing one integer with another integer in the same format, and comparing two floating point numbers.

In the case of integer comparison, the integer format used will be such that it's possible to compare two values in a very straightforward way, looking at specific bits in a certain order (sign bits, high-order bits, then low-order bits).

In the case of floating point numbers, the vast majority of values will be represented [in a normalised form](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/), so you can just compare, in order:

- the corresponding sign bits, then if they are equal
- the corresponding exponents, then if they are equal
- the corresponding mantissas (high to low order bits, bitwise).

These sorts of comparison are so common and so important in general processors that they will be optimised for speed.